# how to set menu item not cliquable android with textcolor white?

Tags: android, menuitem

I have a menu in the Action bar of my tablet. In my style i puted Android TextColor white. but I would like to remove the click Action of my Item so I tried  `item.setEnabled(false);` but the problem with this command that my text will be in grey not in white.

Answer (score 0):

Android puts the color to gray to make it clear to the user that it's not enabled. If you really want it to stay white, don't use setEnebled(false) but just don't handle the click event.